# How to insert compound objects or for loops within a data.table by groups?

Tags: r, data.table

What is the easiest/fastest way to convert an rbinded loop of data.table operations into a data.table of loops?

Toy example:

```
set.seed(1)
DT <- data.table(ID=rep(1:3, each=3),
city=sample(rep(LETTERS[1:3],3),size=9,replace=F),
pop=runif(9))

   ID city        pop
1:  1    C 0.06178627
2:  1    A 0.20597457
3:  1    A 0.17655675
4:  2    A 0.68702285
5:  2    B 0.38410372
6:  2    C 0.76984142
7:  3    C 0.49769924
8:  3    B 0.71761851
9:  3    B 0.99190609
```

Now, using nested loops, I can create a simple code which gives for each ID the first occurence of each city and the value of pop at a given position.

```
output <- data.table()
for(ii in LETTERS[1:3]) { 
  for(jj in 1:2) {
    output <- rbindlist(list(output,DT[,.(ii,jj,
          which(city==ii)[1],pop[jj]), by=ID]))
  }
}
```

This is the output:

```
    ID ii jj V3         V4
 1:  1  A  1  2 0.06178627
 2:  2  A  1  1 0.68702285
 3:  3  A  1 NA 0.49769924
 4:  1  A  2  2 0.20597457
 5:  2  A  2  1 0.38410372
 6:  3  A  2 NA 0.71761851
 7:  1  B  1 NA 0.06178627
 8:  2  B  1  2 0.68702285
 9:  3  B  1  2 0.49769924
10:  1  B  2 NA 0.20597457
11:  2  B  2  2 0.38410372
12:  3  B  2  2 0.71761851
13:  1  C  1  1 0.06178627
14:  2  C  1  3 0.68702285
15:  3  C  1  1 0.49769924
16:  1  C  2  1 0.20597457
17:  2  C  2  3 0.38410372
18:  3  C  2  1 0.71761851
```

I would like to move the loops into the "j" position of the data.table brackets (*).

After much trying I got it using:

```
DT[,rbindlist(lapply(LETTERS[1:3], function(ii)
 rbindlist(lapply(1:2,function(jj) .(ii,jj, 
 which(city==ii)[1],pop[jj]) ) ) )), by=ID]
```

It wasn't easy for me to find a working solution because of the incompatible intermediate outputs and expected inputs of each function, bygroups...

Is there any other faster or simpler way to achieve the same?

(*): My real exercise has 3 loops and more complex computations. Moving the loops into de brackets I can make some extra simplifications.

I've found an alternative a little bit faster than my other option though slower than the loop. The good news is it needs less memory.

```
DT[,transpose( sapply(LETTERS[1:3], function(ii)(lapply(
 1:2,function(jj)  c(ii,jj, which(city==ii)[1],
 pop[jj]) ) ) )), by=ID]
```

Comment: @akrun I'm sorry. Fixed.
You can use any function or example you like.

Comment: Try ` DT[, lapply(1:3, `*`, 1:3), by = ID]`

Comment: I am sorry, I didn't get the full picture of what you seek.  Do you want to optimize the `for` loop ?

Comment: How can I force data.table to accept a bidimensional object instead of an unidimensional list for each ID?
For example each ID produces 3 vectors of the same lenght and I want to rbind everythng.

Comment: You may use `Map` or `lapply` inside that as I showed in the example based on your original example data

Comment: @akrun please read my new question, with a simpler example. I have already achieved an ugly solution.

Comment: I think your explanation of the task at hand could be improved.